# if/else logic in gitlab ci based on return code of python script

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` file that I'm invoking a `python` script from like:

```
- /usr/bin/python3.6 file.py
```

This `file.py` file returns either `True` or `False`

In pseudocode I'm trying to do:

```
- run file.py
- if True: do x
- else do y
```

How can I achieve this in `gitlabci` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How does it return `True` or `False` - by writing to stdout?

If so then

```
- RES=$(run file.py)
- |
  if [[ $RES == "True" ]]; then
    ...
  else
    ...
  fi
```